# HTML - The above navbar scroll when user scroll and become smaller

Tags: css, html

I want the navbar like this site

[Example](http://datasenz.com)

The navbar follow the user scroll and become smaller.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made an effort to research the answer yourself? Take a look at [these tips](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in asking questions on SO.

Comment: right click > inspect-element >follow the stylesheets

Comment: I have search, but all of my result it by fixing the css rule and it cant get smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This navbar is accomplished with javascript and jquery.

They are using the .scrollTop jquery method to add the class .min (which has the smaller height properties) and CSS easing to make the transition smoother.

Here's the javascript code they are using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.main-nav').css('display', 'none');
$('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
    $('.main-nav').slideToggle('medium');
});
//Relevant Code Starts Here
$(window).scroll(function(){
             // If the scroll bar is at the position of 30px or less
    if($(window).scrollTop() <= 30){
            //Remove the css class of min - this is where the page starts
        $('.top-nav').removeClass('min')
    }else{
            //Add the css class of min
        $('.top-nav').addClass('min')
    }
});
});
```

Here is the CSS they are using for easing:

```
.top-nav{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
 }
```

Here's a tool that can help you to create your own easing animations:

http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/